# User not able to log into the community

Tags: community, profile, user

I would like add users to my newly created community.

The community is created and has its URL and all. I created a new User and gave him the profile `alpha`. Then in the community's adminstrative settings I added the profile alpha to the members area.

When I try to log in to the community at the URL, it says "Your login attempt has failed".

This is driving me mad. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: What kind of community did you create, a customer community, chatter community, etc? Did you clone the profile with the license that supports that community when you created the profile you named `alpha`?

Comment: Is the community published or offline ?